# Programmatically read from library

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007, xslt

I have a document library named "xsl library" with a bunch of xsl's... and I need to read a file (anyone one) from there so  I can use it transform a xml that renders a webpart... the layout out of a webpart is determined by the xsl... how can I do it?

Notes: Enviroment -> Sharepoint 2007

Comment: Will need more information. What is the way these 'xsl' are to be retrieved (are they properties, single property of type array). You may also want to provide some sample code you are currently using for utilizing these libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like you need some server side code:

```
SPFile xslFile = SPContext.Current.Web.GetFile("/myWeb/myXlsLibrary/myXsl.xsl"); 
Stream xslStream = xslFile.OpenBinaryStream();
```

Then you code similar to one provided by Vlad above to make the transformation.

See MSDN for more info on functions used - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getfile.aspx , http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.openbinarystream.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

```
XslCompiledTransform proc = new XslCompiledTransform();

proc.Load(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(stringWithXsltStylesheetCode)));

XmlDocument result = new XmlDocument();
using (XmlWriter xw = result.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
{
   proc.Transform(inputXmlDocument, null, xw);
   xw.Close();
}
```

Comment: the problem here is not how to transform the xml... but how to read the file from the Document Library without downloading it...

Comment: "read ... without donwloading" - what do you mean? Do you need to do it on SharePoint server itself (using SharePoint object model) or from other machine/browser?

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov the webpart need a xsl for style itself... the xsl is pointed in the config (its not always the same) and it can be found (the xsl) in the "xsl library"... i need the webpart to read the pointed xsl from the library and transform itself...